# Is there a list of popular iOS twitter clients and their custom URL schemes for following and tweeting?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, url-scheme

I assume every serious twitter client supports custom url schemes such that developers can send pre-compose tweets or suggest users to follow someone.

I wasn't particularly lucky finding such a list. Before I spent a day dealing with all of the different twitter client websites, maybe someone can point out a great resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [iPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) list useful then.

Listed URL schemes include sending tweets via:
Twitterriffic, Twittelator, Twinkle, Tweetie and maybe even more

Answer (score 4):

http://handleopenurl.com/
It has a ton of apps in addition to twitter apps.